# Displaying some HTML code in my Rails view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller, I'm outputting some HTML that I want to give to the user to copy but not have that HTML render what it actually renders on the page.

Here's the code from my `show` action:

```
@url = <iframe src=#{url} scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden;width:800px; height:21px;\" allowtransparency=\"true\" ></iframe>
```

What should I do differently so the view will display the HTML properly, the user can just copy the whole thing, paste it and be good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your HTML, and you can use `html_escape()` or aliased method `h()` to do this. In your view, where you currently have something like:

```
<%= @url %>
```

change to:

```
<%=h @url %>
```

For further info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape

Answer (score 0):

in your view try this:

```
<%=raw(@url)%>
```

some usefull information can be found here:

http://www.tigraine.at/2012/08/23/when-to-use-raw-and-when-to-use-html_safe

Comment: Should my URL be escaped?

Comment: edited, read the article in the link to know when to scape your code